# JS functions within HTML executing when not being called

Tags: html

The issue I am having is that my functions are being called and attempting to execute despite me not calling them yet.

This is the error:

[image: this is the error]

This is the code:
[image: this is the code]

I put type has text/js in the head which was a common solution that was being suggested. The issue isn't really impacting me at the moment but with what I would like to do I feel it could become an issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try not to add image for errors or codes

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

At the time your `JS` code got executed, there was no element with the id `name` or `height`. Resulted in returning null.

So, what you have to do is place the `script` tag in the bottom of `body` tag like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Some code here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Some code here -->
        <script>
            <!-- Your JS code here -->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this way, `JS` code will be executed after `html`

**One More Thing:-** You are assigning the `onclick` function two times on the submit button, and that's redundant. So change this line

```
<button id ="1" onclick="submit()">submit</button>
```

to this line:

```
<button id ="1">submit</button>
```

Comment: You have duplicate event, since you have assign onclick to document.getElementById('1') you can get rid of the onclick in yor button tag.